# How to make objects move with CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

I have two images (objects) set side by side in the middle of the page and I want them to move toward each other as if they are going to collide and stop as they are placed beside each one.

So, for the object at the right side I have written the following code, thinking that the object should move from left to right, but the result is far from what I expect. Is it possible to do it by transition? what I want is that one of the objects start moving from left side and the other start moving from the right and meet at the center as if they want to collide.

```css
.one {
  border: 3px solid #73AD21;
  position: absolute;
}
.two {
  top: 45%;
  left: 44%;
}
.left1,
.right2 {
  float: left;
}
#axis:hover .move-right {
  transform: translate(-350px, 0);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-350px, 0);
  -o-transform: translate(-350px, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate(-350px, 0);
}
.object1 {
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 2s ease-in;
  -webkit-transition: all 2s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: all 2s ease-in;
  -o-transition: all 2s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<div id="axis" class="one two">
  <img class="object1 left1 move-right" src="http://placehold.it/50x50" />
  <img class="object2 right2 move-left" src="http://placehold.it/75x75" />
</div>
```

Comment: You don’t have an animation, you have a transition.... They aren't the same thing.

Comment: You might want to use keyframes for that : https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/keyframe-animation-syntax/

Comment: If you want to stick with your transition code, you could change your `:hover` identifier to a new class (like '.animating', for a generic example) and then use javascript to add that class to your element.

Comment: @Brian D 6- yes I know JS would be a better answer, but don't know where to start. Do you have any samples for me to refer to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have two images [...] what I want is that one of the objects start moving from left side and the other start moving from the right and meet at the center as if they want to collide.
>
> *Is it possible to do it by transition?*

Yes it is - if I have understood your question correctly.

An important consideration with `CSS transitions` is that you should explicitly set the start-state and the end-state, so the browser is clear what it is transitioning between.

So... in the example you post in your question, it's important to state the `translateX` position for the images when `:hover` applies, *but also* when `:hover` doesn't apply.

That way, the browser can be clear what two `translateX` co-ordinates it is transitioning between.

**Example:**

```css
#axis {
border: 3px solid #73AD21;
position: absolute;
top: 45%;
left: 44%;
}

#axis img {
float: left;
transition: all 1s ease-in;
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in;
-moz-transition: all 1s ease-in;
-o-transition: all 1s ease-in;
}

#axis .move-left {
transform: translateX(200px);
-webkit-transform: translateX(200px);
-o-transform: translateX(200px);
-moz-transform: translateX(200px);
}

#axis .move-right {
transform: translateX(-200px);
-webkit-transform: translateX(-200px);
-o-transform: translateX(-200px);
-moz-transform: translateX(-200px);
}


#axis:hover .move-left, #axis:hover .move-right {
transform: translateX(0px);
-webkit-transform: translateX(0);
-o-transform: translateX(0);
-moz-transform: translateX(0);
}

p {
font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<p>Hover over the green border box.</p>

<div id="axis">
<img class="move-right" src="http://placehold.it/50x50" />
<img class="move-left" src="http://placehold.it/75x75" />
</div>
```

---

## Version 2 (move just once when the page loads)

```js
function initialiseAxisImages() {
var axis = document.getElementById('axis');
var axisImages = axis.getElementsByTagName('img');

axisImages[0].classList.remove('move-right');
axisImages[1].classList.remove('move-left');
}

window.addEventListener('load', initialiseAxisImages, false);
```

```css
#axis {
border: 3px solid #73AD21;
position: absolute;
top: 45%;
left: 44%;
}

#axis img {
float: left;
transition: all 1s ease-in;
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in;
-moz-transition: all 1s ease-in;
-o-transition: all 1s ease-in;
}

#axis .move-left {
transform: translateX(200px);
-webkit-transform: translateX(200px);
-o-transform: translateX(200px);
-moz-transform: translateX(200px);
}

#axis .move-right {
transform: translateX(-200px);
-webkit-transform: translateX(-200px);
-o-transform: translateX(-200px);
-moz-transform: translateX(-200px);
}
```

```html
<div id="axis">
<img class="move-right" src="http://placehold.it/50x50" />
<img class="move-left" src="http://placehold.it/75x75" />
</div>
```

Comment: is there a way to have this move only once, just when the pages loads?

Comment: Yes, you can remove the `:hover` declarations from the CSS and add a small `javascript` which fires just once, when the page loads. (See **Version 2** above).

Comment: I think the extra div tags are causing trouble. Here is my test fiddle: `http://jsfiddle.net/sryzdn/4mhvndu9/`

Comment: In your fiddle what you are referring to as `axisImages[1]` is actually `axisImages[6]`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not strong in javascript, so I generally lean on jQuery.
If I were solving it with jQuery I'd decide when I wanted my animation to start then use this code to animate my element:

```
$('#axis .move-right').addClass('animate');
```

Here's an example that adds the class `.animate` when you click on the `#axis` element.

```js
//binds an anonymous function to the 'click' event on #axis
$('#axis').on('click',function(){ 

  //adds your 'animation' class that triggers the CSS animation
  $('#axis .move-right').addClass('animate');

});
```

```css
.one {
  border: 3px solid #73AD21;
  position: absolute;
}
.two {
  top: 45%;
  left: 44%;
}
.left1,
.right2 {
  float: left;
}
#axis .move-right.animate {
  transform: translate(-350px, 0);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-350px, 0);
  -o-transform: translate(-350px, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate(-350px, 0);
}
.object1 {
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 2s ease-in;
  -webkit-transition: all 2s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: all 2s ease-in;
  -o-transition: all 2s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="axis" class="one two">
  <img class="object1 left1 move-right" src="http://placehold.it/50x50" />
  <img class="object2 right2 move-left" src="http://placehold.it/75x75" />
</div>
```

See this updated fiddle for one of the boxes moving into the middle:
https://jsfiddle.net/fuce0x67/

```js
//binds an anonymous function to the 'click' event on #axis
$('#axis').on('click',function(){ 

  //adds your 'animation' class that triggers the CSS animation
  $('#axis .move-right').addClass('animate');

});
```

```css
.one {
  border: 3px solid #73AD21;
  position: absolute;
}
.two {
  top: 45%;
  left: 44%;
}
.left1,
.right2 {
  float: left;
}
#axis .move-right { //removed animate class from here. This is now the 'default' (pre-animation) position for this element
  transform: translate(-350px, 0);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-350px, 0);
  -o-transform: translate(-350px, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate(-350px, 0);
}

#axis .move-right.animate {//added this block to reset the positions to ~center like I think you want
  transform: translate(-70px, 0);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-70px, 0);
  -o-transform: translate(-70px, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate(-70px, 0);
}

.object1 {
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 2s ease-in;
  -webkit-transition: all 2s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: all 2s ease-in;
  -o-transition: all 2s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="axis" class="one two">
  <img class="object1 left1 move-right" src="http://placehold.it/50x50" />
  <img class="object2 right2 move-left" src="http://placehold.it/75x75" />
</div>

<p>
click on the box in the center to activate animation
</p>
```

Comment: you could also toggle the animation state by using `.toggleClass` instead of `.addClass`

Comment: Thanks, what I want is that one of the objects start from left side and the other start from the right and meet at the center.

Comment: So then you need to code your "default" state (the two positioned away from the center), then code the end state for the animation (the two sitting adjacent in the center) as part of your `.animate` class, then when you trigger the animation, you add the `animate` class to both elements and the CSS will take care of the rest.

Comment: yes, what I have sent here is actually the end part. I want to show that the two images are coming from the outside as the initial step, but I don't know how to code it.

Comment: That's easy; just swap your `animate` and default styles in the CSS.

Comment: Updated my answer with `.move-right` box animating in from the left.

Comment: I'm gonna try it. Thank you so much.

Comment: is there any way I can change "click" to "load"? I mean this happens when the page loads?

Comment: `$(document).ready(function(){ $('#axis .move-right').addClass('animate'); });` should do the trick. Instead of binding an anonymous function to the 'click' event, we're binding that same anonymous function to the event that is triggered when the document tells the browser "Everything is loaded. I'm ready!" - See updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fuce0x67/1/

Comment: You're awesome! Thank you.