# horizontal li elements after pseudo-element transition

Tags: html, css, sass

I have a horizontal menu with a right arrow in after pseudo element. the after have a transition on hover. the issue is if i hover the sibling element moves also.

html

`<ul>
<li>item 1</li>
<li> item 2</li>
<li> item 3</li>
</ul>`

scss

```
ul {
 list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;

  li {
    float: left;
    padding: 20px;

   &::after {
      content: " > ";
      width: 35px;
      height: 35px;
      transition: margin-left 0.1s ease-out;
    }

   &:hover {
      &::after {
        margin-left: 10px;
      }
   }
  }
}
```

my question: how to stop the sibling element movement?

NB: The content of the menu item come from CMS so i can't set a width

Comment: Use `transition: transform` instead of `transition: margin-left`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35250822/how-to-make-objects-move-with-css/35252609#35252609

Answer (score 0):

By using position property(in our case we used position: absolute) we took the element('>') out from the normal document flow, so this element won't be effecting any of the content from  the normal document flow (in our case sibling li's).

```
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  li {
    float: left;
    padding: 20px;
    position: relative;
   &::after {
      position: absolute;
      content: " > ";
      width: 35px;
      height: 35px;
      transition: margin-left 0.1s ease-out;
    }
   &:hover {
      &::after {
        margin-left: 10px;     
      }
   }
  }
}
```